# Swift Code for reducing / compressing pictures saved to parse

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, image-compression

Please look at the code below if you believe there is anything that can be done to improve the swift code please let me know - I converted this code from objective-c off the raw engineering website [www.rawend.com](http://www.raweng.com/blog/2013/03/04/improving-image-compression-what-weve-learned-from-whatsapp/)

@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profilePic.image)

    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

    func compressImage(image:UIImage) -> NSData {
        // Reducing file size to a 10th

        var actualHeight : CGFloat = image.size.height
        var actualWidth : CGFloat = image.size.width
        var maxHeight : CGFloat = 1136.0
        var maxWidth : CGFloat = 640.0
        var imgRatio : CGFloat = actualWidth/actualHeight
        var maxRatio : CGFloat = maxWidth/maxHeight
        var compressionQuality : CGFloat = 0.5

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth){
            if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
                //adjust width according to maxHeight
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
                actualHeight = maxHeight;
            }
            else if(imgRatio > maxRatio){
                //adjust height according to maxWidth
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
                actualWidth = maxWidth;
            }
            else{
                actualHeight = maxHeight;
                actualWidth = maxWidth;
                compressionQuality = 1;
            }
        }

        var rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        image.drawInRect(rect)
        var img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality);
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return imageData;
    }

    let compressedImage = compressImage(image!)

    let picture = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: compressedImage)

    PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(picture, forKey: "profilePic")
    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            println("image has been saved")
        } else {
            println("image failed")
        }
    }
}
```